# Paginar relaciones muchos a muchos

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo dos tablas:

- una de video
- otra de tag

Su relación es de muchos a muchos

- utilizo el slug como key en lugar de usar el id

Cuando accedo a la vista de video en esta se listan todos sus tag, al momento de hacer clic en un tag me dirige a otra vista donde se listan todos los videos con ese tag.

Suponiendo que en un futuro la aplicación crecerá, la vista se llenará de resultados, mi intención es paginar esos resultados

Aqui el controlador

```
public function TagShow($slug){

    $videoTag = Tag::select('tags.*')
        ->where('slug','=', $slug)
        ->firstOrFail();

    return view('front.TagShow', compact('videoTag'));

}
```

aqui la vista donde hago un foreach y muestro los registros de la bd

```
@foreach($videoTag->videos as $video)
<div class="post-content">
   <div class="post-image">
      <div>
         <img src="{{asset('images/'.$video->picture)}}" class="img" alt="{{$video->name}}">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-title">
       <a href="{!! action('FrontController@show', [$video->slug]) !!}">
          {{$video->name}}
       </a>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Paginar con base al TAG, en los modelos si estan creadas las relaciones (las he usado para el CRUD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumiendo que tienes los siguientes modelos:

- **`Video`**
- **`Tag`**

Cada uno de ellos debe tener una relación del tipo **`belongsToMany`** apuntando al otro modelo para completar la relación de muchos a muchos de esta forma:

Modelo Tag

```
public function videos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Video::class);
}
```

Modelo Video

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
}
```

Entonces si necesitas paginar todos los videos que pertenecen a una categoría tu consulta debería estar así:

```
$data = Tag::with('videos')->whereSlug($slug)->paginate(10);
```

Lo que hicimos fue:

- Invocar al modelo **`Tag`** y cargarle sus relaciones a través del método **`videos()`** que debemos tener declarado en dicho modelo
- Encontramos la coincidencia indicando en el **`WHERE`** que solo buscamos por el **slug**
- Finalmente paginamos los resultados